# Maintain a state in apache beam (google dataflow) pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow deployed in Google Cloud. I am looking for a way to set a trace id so that it is available in all steps of the pipeline.

One way that i was thinking is to create a trace id and set it in each step :

ex:

Step A (create and set trace id) --> Step B (read and set to message C) --> Step C (read and set to message D --> Step D (read trace id).

Is there any better way to make the trace id available in all steps ?

Srinivas

I tried to create a set the trace id in each step.

Comment: The trace id is the same for all the job or you generate a trace ID per first element of the pipeline ?

Comment: The idea is to have the same trace id for all the steps within the pipeline.

Comment: For all steps but not for all elements in the PCollection ?